# how OS know encoding of files

Tags: encoding, utf-8, operating-system

For example I have a file on my disk: a.txt
I opened it in Hex mode and see no other signal character in it but plain text in UTF-8.

I am wondering how OS know it is UTF-8??

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OS doesn't know. The hex editor is probably auto-detecting it. That's possible by looking out for the presence and absence of specific byte pairs, but it's not 100% reliable.

There is no general flag or property in which a file's encoding is stored. That's why you often need to specify the encoding manually when opening a text file.

One approach to mark a UTF-8 or -16 file is the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) but that's not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

The OS has no concept of text file encoding. Text editors usually guess from the contents, or assume UTF-8 or default to your locale's encoding.